# C++ float to string conversion failing with stringstream

Tags: c++, string, arduino, floating-point, particle.io

I am working on the particle.io Spark platform, currently stuck trying to print out a float as a string. I saw some solutions where you use a string stream to convert the float.

My implementation is as follows below:

```
#include <sstream>

void loop()
{
    float tempC = 21.35;

    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << tempC;
    std::string tempCString = stream.str();

    // why does this give me a blank string?
    Serial.print("Temp 1: ");
    Serial.println(tempCString.c_str());

    // while this outputs the float
    Serial.print("Temp 2: ");
    Serial.println(tempC);

    Serial.println(tempCString.size());
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Temp 1:
Temp 2: 21.35
6
```

Also, this fails to compile:

```
Serial.println(tempCString);
```

With the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'USBSerial::println(std::string&)'
```

Edit: link to particle docs about Serial.print

https://docs.particle.io/reference/firmware/core/#print-

Comment: What is `Serial`? Are you on Arduino?

Comment: Similar to Arduino, I'm using a particle.io spark.

Comment: May be you should provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem and leave out the non standard parts.

Comment: He's exemple is fine imo

Comment: clarified the code to make it more complete, minimal, verifiable

Comment: Well, then, Treyco .... how about you explain what `Serial` does.   It is non-standard, and from (lack of) information given could well be the culprit.

Comment: What are the overloads of `println`?

Comment: @Peter Its an arduino function used to print like printf..., if you don't know about the API he's using you obviously won't find the answer

Comment: print and println output strings without problems, so i would guess the issue is with converting the float to a string.

Comment: `c_str()` should work since `"Temp 1: "` works whatever the API. I replaced `println` by a mere `printf` and first part worked fine...

Comment: @koverda: have you tried the `sprintf(temp_string,"%f",tempC)` ?

Comment: koverda: Did you mean `Serial.println(tempCString);` fails to compile?  (It would match your error message better).  If so, that just means `println` has no overloads which take a `std::string` - you need to call `.c_str()` first.

Comment: @MartinBonner not exactly sure what you mean by calling .c_str() first.

Comment: "first" was probably unhelpful.  You have to do what you did:  instead of `Serial.println(str);` use `Serial.println(str.c_str());`

Comment: did you mean that `Serial.println(tempCString.c_str());` will compile? Indeed it does, but it does not print the float as a string for me.

Comment: Also - adding something else to the stringstream doesn't change the output. `stream << tempC << "hello";` still leads to an output of `Temp 1:`

Comment: @koverda: Try `Serial.println(tempCString.size());` - if that outputs "0", there is something strange going on.  Can you get a debugger on this thing?  If not, add a `std::flush`?? (that is clutching at straws).

Comment: however `stream << "hi" << tempC << "hello";` leads to an output of `Temp 1: hi`

Comment: @MartinBonner `Serial.println(tempCString.size());` gives an output of 6, which makes sense - 5 chars and the terminator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125568/discussion-between-martin-bonner-and-koverda).

Comment: @MartinBonner not sure if i can really get a debugger going, as this is running on a little piece of hardware sitting on my desk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Not sure if this holds true for regular c++, but for the version of c++ running on the particle spark, the solution is as follows:

```
float myFloat = 6.123;
String floatString(myFloat, 2);
```

This gives me a string that I can work with!